# long running service on Android 13

Tags: android, performance, service

My Android app has a long running service. You can close the app, and the service will continue to run. Even if the phone is sleeping, the service will continue to run. However starting in Android 13, after around 2 hours the service gets terminated. On some phones, it is 8 hours. Do you know why this is? Do you know how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Is it a foreground service?

Comment: Sorry, but can I wonder what your service does? IMO, I think there is no way to keep a very long running service from being terminated by the system. When a phone runs into doze mode, it'll restrict all the apps to conserve its battery. But if we know what your service intends to do, we may find you another proper solution.

Comment: sorry for the late response. The app tracks a driver by sending his latitude/longitude to the server. This seemed to work fine in Android 12

Comment: Any have find solution regarding android 13?